# Express js server to handle webcam stream to multiple clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I'm creating a proxy server for Octoprint. The server's point is to be a read-only way for us to give out printer status without making people log in to octo prints UI. I got most of the stuff working where I can ping the target printer and get its status. The problem has been the webcam stream. Currently, I'm making one request to the printer and getting the webcam stream from it. The server works great for a few clients, but once another person concurrently requests the webpage, it holds up the entire server and makes it so no more requests come through. I've tried making multiple stream connections to the Octoprint server and I get the same result. Our goal is to be able to make one connection to the Octoprint server to stop overhead on that server side. But be able to proxy the webcam and status data to clients.

this is my function for getting the octoprint connection

```
export async function getPrinterVideo(printer_url: string, api_key: string): Promise<stream.Readable> {
    try {
        const options: AxiosRequestConfig = {
            'headers': {
                'X-Api-Key': api_key,
                'Content-Type': `multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=boundarydonotcross`,
            },
            decompress: false,

            responseType: 'stream',
        }
        var connection_url = printer_url + "/webcam/?action=stream"
        var res_from_octo = await axios.get(connection_url, options)
        return res_from_octo.data as stream.Readable
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("unable to find stream")
    }

}
```

and this is the endpoint

```
    constructor(name: string, url: string, api_key: string) {

        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
        this.api_key = api_key;
        this.ready = false;
        var me = this
        pingPrinter(this.url, this.api_key).then(() => {
            me.getVideo();
            me.refresh().then(() => {
                this.ready = true;
            })

        }).catch(() => {
            this.ready = false;
        })


        this.buildApi()
    }
    async getVideo() {
        this.printer_video = await getPrinterVideo(this.url, this.api_key);
    }
    getVideoStream(): stream.Readable {
        if (!this.printer_video) {
            return this.getVideoStream()
        }
        return this.printer_video
    }

buildApi(){
        this.router = Router();

  this.router.get('/video', async (req, res) => {
            try {
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': `multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=boundarydonotcross`,
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                    'X-Accel-Buffering': 'no',
                });

                res.on('close', () => {
                    this.getVideoStream().unpipe(res);
                });

                this.getVideoStream().pipe(res);


            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        })
}
```